# Producing multiple plots from data-frame using columns as y-axis values (looping through dataframe)

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame such as below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKKrz.png]

Two categorical variables are *impulsivity* and *treatment* and multiple dependent variables (*prot_width* etc..).

I have managed to produce a boxplot that models the dependent variable by *impulsivity* and *treatment*;

```
sns.boxplot(x='treatment', y='prot_width', hue='impulsivity',
            palette=['b','r'], data=data)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

which produces the graph below;

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfXn1.png]

Now what I want to do is produce the exact same graph but for each dependent variable. I want to loop through each dependent variable column renaming the y-axis.

I have searched for for loops etc. but can't work out how to call the columns and more importantly how to change the y-axis during the loop.

Comment: Simply loop through `data.columns[4:len(data.columns)]` which is a list and pass iterator variable into *y* argument of `boxplot`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am relatively new to python and still having a little difficulty with 'passing the iterator variable'. Does this mean I have to set up a new 'for' statement defining the column headings (with a +1 indexing statement) - not sure if I have confused the issue here. Any help with an example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop through the numeric data columns using `DataFrame.columns` which is an iterable object and then pass iterator variable (here being *col*) into *y* argument of boxplot.

```
for col in data.columns[4:len(data.columns)]:
    sns.boxplot(x='treatment', y=col, hue='impulsivity',
                palette=['b','r'], data=data)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)

    plt.show()
```

Alternatively use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for all numeric columns:

```
for col in data.select_dtypes(['float', 'int']).columns:
    ...
```

Or even [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to leave out non-numeric columns:

```
for col in data.filter(regex="[^(subject|protrusion|impulsivity|treatment)]").columns:
    ...
```

---

To demonstrate with random data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(9192018)
demo_df = pd.DataFrame({'tool': np.random.choice(['pandas', 'r', 'julia', 'sas', 'stata', 'spss'],500),
                        'os': np.random.choice(['windows', 'mac', 'linux'],500), 
                        'prot_width': np.random.randn(500)*100,
                        'prot_length': np.random.uniform(0,1,500),                   
                        'prot_lwr': np.random.randint(100, size=500)
                       }, columns=['tool', 'os', 'prot_width', 'prot_length', 'prot_lwr'])

for col in demo_df.columns[2:len(demo_df.columns)]:
    sns.boxplot(x='tool', y=col, hue='os', palette=['b','r'], data=demo_df)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)

    plt.legend(loc='center', ncol = 3, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.10))
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

plt.close()
```

[image: Plot Output]